# Flutter zoomable image with overlays

Tags: image, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, overlay

I'm trying to make a custom widget that the user can zoom and pan an image and tap to overlay points on the image.  I think I'm close but can't quite get the points to line up under the tap.

I copied the relevant zoom-pan from here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/widgets/gestures.dart

I also have my GestureDetector pulled out into its own widget as per this post to get the correct RenderBox for global to local offset conversion
[flutter : Get Local position of Gesture Detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52000130/flutter-get-local-position-of-gesture-detector)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageWithOverlays extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<FractionalOffset> fractionalOffsets;
  ImageWithOverlays(this.fractionalOffsets);

  @override
  _ImageWithOverlaysState createState() => _ImageWithOverlaysState();    
}


class _ImageWithOverlaysState extends State<ImageWithOverlays> {
  Offset _startingFocalPoint;
  Offset _previousOffset;
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;

  double _previousZoom;
  double _zoom = 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onScaleStart: _handleScaleStart,
        onScaleUpdate:_handleScaleUpdate,
        onTapDown: (details){          
          setState(() {                        
            widget.fractionalOffsets.add(_getFractionalOffset(context, details.globalPosition));             
          });
        },
        onDoubleTap: _handleScaleReset,
        child: Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(_zoom, _zoom, 1.0) + Matrix4.translationValues(_offset.dx, _offset.dy, 0.0),         
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
              child:Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(
                  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                ), ]
                ..addAll(_getOverlays(context)),
            )),
          ),
      ));
     
  }

  void _handleScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _startingFocalPoint = details.focalPoint;
      _previousOffset = _offset;
      _previousZoom = _zoom;
    });
  }


  void _handleScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _zoom = _previousZoom * details.scale;

      // Ensure that item under the focal point stays in the same place despite zooming
      final Offset normalizedOffset = (_startingFocalPoint - _previousOffset) / _previousZoom;
      _offset = details.focalPoint - normalizedOffset * _zoom;
    });
  }

  void _handleScaleReset() {
    setState(() {
      _zoom = 1.0;
      _offset = Offset.zero;
      widget.fractionalOffsets.clear();
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _getOverlays(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.fractionalOffsets
        .asMap() 
        .map((i, fo) => MapEntry(
            i,
            Align(
                alignment: fo,
                child: _buildIcon((i + 1).toString(), context)
            )           
        ))
        .values
        .toList();
  }

  Widget _buildIcon(String indexText, BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton.icon(      
      icon: Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.red),
      label: Text(
        indexText,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),      
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCircleIcon(String indexText) {
    return Container(          
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child:  Text(
                indexText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
              ));
  }

  FractionalOffset _getFractionalOffset(BuildContext context, Offset globalPosition) {    
    var renderbox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    var localOffset = renderbox.globalToLocal(globalPosition);
    var width = renderbox.size.width;
    var height = renderbox.size.height;
    return FractionalOffset(localOffset.dx/width,localOffset.dy/height); 
  }
}
```

But I'm having a rough time getting the layout right.  I think I have two issues:

1. The image likes to jump to the upper left.  I'm not sure how to get it to stay centered.
   [image]
2. When I zoom in, my _getFractionalOffset function is not returning the correct fraction.  The icons in this screenshot are not showing up under my tap
   [image]
   My matrix math is poor, as is my understanding of how Flutter does its transforms, so I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55324411/2252830

Comment: @pskink this looks like a nice wrapper for scaling and panning, but I need to get the location from GestureDetector's TapDownDetails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, I had a couple issues with my code that when compounded made debugging annoying.

First, I should have been multiplying the scale/translate matrices, not adding them:

```
vector.Matrix4 get _transformationMatrix {
  var scale = vector.Matrix4.diagonal3Values(_zoom, _zoom, 1.0);
  var translation = vector.Matrix4.translationValues(_offset.dx, _offset.dy, 0.0);
  var transform = translation * scale;
  return transform;
}
```

Second, I was trying to fuss around with doing the translating from local offset to the image frame instead of letting vector_math do it for me.  The new overlay offset calculation:

```
Offset _getOffset(BuildContext context, Offset globalPosition) {    
  var renderbox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  var localOffset = renderbox.globalToLocal(globalPosition);    
  var localVector = vector.Vector3(localOffset.dx, localOffset.dy,0);
  var transformed =  Matrix4.inverted(_transformationMatrix).transform3(localVector);
  return Offset(transformed.x, transformed.y);
}
```

Since `_transformationmatrix` takes a point from the image frame to the screen frame, I needed to left multiply the inverse to get from the screen frame (`localOffset`) to the image frame (returned value).

Finally, I'm using the Positioned widget instead of Align so I can set the positioning in pixels:

```
double _width = 100;
double _height = 50;
List<Widget> _getOverlays(BuildContext context) {
  return widget.points
      .asMap() 
      .map((i, offset) => MapEntry(
          i,
          Positioned(
              left: offset.dx-_width/2,
              width:_width,
              top: offset.dy -_height/2,
              height:_height,
              child: _buildIcon((i + 1).toString(), context)
          )           
      ))
      .values
      .toList();
}
```

where `widget.points` is a `List<Offset>` of offsets returned by `_getOffset` above, and `width`/`height` are the width and height of my icon widget.

Hope this helps someone!